# Piping output in Python: multiple channels for data and messages?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm doing some python programming, and I would like to "pipe" the output of one program to another. That's easily doable using sys.stdin and sys.stdout. However, I would also like to be able to print info and warning messages to the terminal. Is there any (simple) way to have multiple channels, with messages printed to the terminal, but data being sent to another program?

Comment: Where is this piping happening?  Is your python script dispatching other python scripts directly, or are you piping output from one command to another directly from the terminal?  If you are piping directly on the terminal, your options are fairly limited from Python, since the proverbial horse has already left the stable in that case.  You could, and quite possibly should, then, look at refactoring your code so that Python is in charge instead of the terminal, then you'd have much more control of where data goes and how it gets there from within Python.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `stderr` for terminal output and `stdout` for the pipe.

You might find [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) useful. It spawns another program as a separate process and allows you to define the file descriptors for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` as you wish.

Comment: +1. In fact, that's one of the major reasons `stderr` exists.

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty much what the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is built for.  You can log messages to loggers you can create and name arbitrarily from anywhere in your code, then by attaching handlers to the loggers, push the data to whatever consumer or consumers you want.

If that doesn't work for you, moooeeeep's subprocess suggestion is probably the next best avenue to explore.  That is kind of the civilized way of accomplishing the same thing as overwriting sys.stdout, which is something that only barbarians and the infirm should ever do.

Comment: I don't see how logging helps. The problem is that stdout is redirected to another program, so if you print log messages to stdout, then they will be sent to that program, as well.

Comment: Actually, I tested it out, and it seems that redirecting stdout doesn't affect the logging output. If you write:

    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(name)s] %(levelname)s :   %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)

Then logging.info("blah") will print "blah" to the terminal, rather than sending it to whereever stdout is redirected.

Comment: That's because the StreamHandler pushes to stderr, not stdout, by default.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, use `stdout` for data and `stderr` for user interaction. Here's how to do it in recent python versions (that is, 3.x and 2.6 or newer):

```
import sys
print("data", file=sys.stdout)
print("more data") # sys.stdout is the default

print("user interaction", file=sys.stderr)
```

The result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
desktop➜  ~  ./tmp.py            
data
more data
user interaction
desktop➜  ~  ./tmp.py > /dev/null 
user interaction
desktop➜  ~  ./tmp.py 2&> /dev/null 
data
more data
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly when I'm wanting to do this quickly I don't mess with the code, I just use tee. Its a *nix utility that does just what you are talking about splitting the pipe for display and piping.  You could farther restrict what you are displaying with a grep.  Great for debugging something that uses pipes.  If this is part of your production system though I probably wouldn't pass info with pipes unless you have to.  If you do, log your errors/warnings and tail -f your log.

I know not really a python answer, but it gets the job done.